# How to check if a promise is resolved and conditional render Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, promise

My objective is to renders a live updating "status" UI that indicates for each service which has resolved and which is still pending & renders a live updating "results" UI that indicates for each service.

Currently I have this code that inmates asynchronous data services called services

```
const returnValues = [
    "Hakuna",
    "Matata",
    "It means",
    "No worries",
    "For the rest of your days"
].sort(() => (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1));
const createService = (retVal, index) => () =>
    new Promise(resolve =>
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(`${index}. ${retVal}`);
            resolve(retVal);
        }, 
        Math.random() * 10000)
    );
const services = returnValues.map(createService);
```

I want to conditionally, render a html template that will indication if the text has been resolved or not

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% clear what all the UI interactions are supposed to be but something like the following might help you along

```js
const returnValues = [
  "Hakuna",
  "Matata",
  "It means",
  "No worries",
  "For the rest of your days"
].sort(() => (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1));

const list = document.querySelector('#list');

const li =(txt)=>{
   const li = document.createElement('li');
   li.textContent = txt;
   return li
}


const createService = (retVal, index) => {
  const el = li(`${index+1} Pending...`);
  list.appendChild(el);
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {     
      resolve(retVal);
    }, Math.random() * 5000)
  }).then(retVal=> {  el.textContent = `${retVal} ...Done`; return retVal})

};
const services = returnValues.map(createService);

Promise.all(services).then((allRetVals)=> list.appendChild(li('ALL DONE!')))
```

```html
<ul id="list">

</ul>
```